# Table in tabularray environment only shows text in first column after multicolumn cell

Tags: tables, multicolumn, tabularray

I am using the tabularray environment to create a multipage table (longtblr) with 6 columns.
After each entry in the table I want to add a row to summarize the entry.
It works for the first entry as intended, but afterwards there is only text in the first column.
I am using the \makecell command to have a linebreak in cells.
What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {This is the caption},
    label   = {tab:test}
    ]
    {
        colspec = {|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        cell{3}{1,7} = {c=6}{l},
        cell{5}{1,7} = {c=6}{l},
    }
        \toprule
        Category 1 &    Category 2 &    Category 3 &    Category 4 & Category 5 & Category 6\\
        \midrule
        \makecell{Entry11 \\ Entry12} & \makecell{Entry21 \\ Entry22} & Entry 3 & Entry 4 & Entry 6 & Entry 7\\
        \midrule
        summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
        \midrule
        test1   &   test2   &   test3   &   test4  &   test5   &   test6\\
        \midrule
        summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
        \midrule
        test12  &   test 22 &   test 32 &   test 42 &   test 52 & test62\\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `cell{3}{1,7} = {c=6}{l}` you not only make the first cell in the row a multicolumn cell, you also make the last cell in the row to span over 6 columns, which will influence the following row.

You also don't need `\makecell` to have line breaks with `tabularray`. A simple `{...}` around your cell will allow you to use line breaks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {This is the caption},
    label   = {tab:test}
    ]
    {
        colspec = {|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        cells = {valign=m},
        cell{3}{1} = {c=6}{l},
        cell{5}{1} = {c=6}{l},
    }
        \toprule
        Category 1 &    Category 2 &    Category 3 &    Category 4 & Category 5 & Category 6\\
        \midrule
        {Entry11 \\ Entry12} & {Entry21 \\ Entry22} & Entry 3 & Entry 4 & Entry 6 & Entry 7\\
        \midrule
        summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
        \midrule
        test1   &   test2   &   test3   &   test4  &   test5   &   test6\\
        \midrule
        summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
        \midrule
        test12  &   test 22 &   test 32 &   test 42 &   test 52 & test62\\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for the explanation. It works for me now :) How can I make Entry 3, Entry4 and so on  vertically centered then?

Comment: @DoPain See my edit. You want to use `valign=m`

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

- Your multicolumn cells are ill defined. Correct definition for your table is given in  @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer, a possible alternative is given in my MWE below

Off-topic, but should be considered:

- Your table width is bigger than `\textwidth`, consequently it spill-out at right text block border.
- one way to solve this problem is to define columns width, which longer text force to break into several lines, or instead `c` column types use `X[c]` or in your case, sine you like to have vertical centered text in cells `X[c,m]`. The latter possibility is exploited in the MWE below.
- instead of `booktabs` rules you can use `\hlines` with defined lines width as is done in my MWE
- `tabullaray` package can simulate `\makecell` with construct `{text \\ text}`.
- If you really need long table, than is sensible to add to table options `rowhead=1`. So far you it seems, that instead `longtblr`, which can span several pages, can be used `talltblr`, which can be insert in `table` float or simple `tblr`, if you not use table notes `TblrNote`, and caption and label move before `tblr` table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {This is the caption},
  label = {tab:test}
                    ]{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2-Y}=solid, vlines,
                      colspec = { *{6}{X[c,m]} },
                      row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                      rowhead = 1
                    }
Category 1  &  Category 2   & Category 3    & Category 4    & Category 5    & Category 6    \\
Entry11  Entry12    
            & {Entry21 \\ Entry22}   % if you wish, you can emulate "makecell" as shown here
                            & Entry 3       & Entry 4       & Entry 6       & Entry 7       \\
\SetCell[c=6]{l}
summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
test1       & test2         &   test3       &   test4       & test5         &   test6       \\
\SetCell[c=6]{l}
summary of the above entry & & & & & \\
test12      &   test 22     &   test 32     &   test 42     & test 52       & test62        \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate part pf cage layout)

Comment: `test2` etc. are missing

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, indeed! Later I will check my answer again ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, my answer is corrected now. I overlook ill define multi cells. However, even befor my answer addressed some (off-topic)  issues. Anyway, I thing downvoting my answer is a bit overwhelming, your comment should be sufficient to remained me on overlooked problem.